# Wordpress create widget with link to local file

Tags: html, wordpress

Hi i´m trying to use the text widget to put a link to local file, but dint work, and I dont know why:

I use this:

```
<a href="file:///D:/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Drive C</a>
```

but if I link to real url it works fine:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Google</a>
```

Comment: so, the html and the file you're trying to access, are on the same computer?

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan, i don´t want to acces to html fil, I want to link to a user local drive. because the domain policies of the network map a shared folder into a local drive, so I want create a link to that local drive

Answer (score 0):

If by local you mean it is still on your laptop, you will need to upload the file to your WordPress installation's media folder before using it on the site.
The images should be acsessable to the sever hosting the site, either because it is stored directly by the server, or because it is can be acsessed over the Internet.

Comment: By local I mean on the client computer, because the domain policies of my network mount a local drive, so I want create a link to that local drive

Answer (score 0):

If by local you mean it is still on your laptop, you will need to upload the file to your WordPress installation's media folder before using on the site.

Due to your response about it being on the client's device I Think they have to upload the file before the server can work with it.